# Delete some items while looping a set

Tags: python, loops, set

I want something like:

```
for node_a in A_nodes:
    a_pos = A.node[node_a]['pos']
    link_len = math.sqrt((a_pos[0]-a_base_pos[0])**2+(b_pos[1]-b_base_pos[1])**2)
    if link_len < th:
        A_nodes.remove(node_a)
```

How to meet my requirements?

Comment: who downvote my question? why?

Comment: waht the function will return ??

Comment: @iCodez  the answerer asked me to change it so as to make it in details...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try like this,

```
myset = { item for item in myset if item<tr}
```

Or,

```
new_set = {}
for item in myset:
   if item < tr:
      new_set.add(item)

myset = new_set
```

Comment: this is a list, not a set. BTW, if there are many lines within the `if` block, the list comprehension may not be a good idea.

Comment: Put your code in curly braces to make a set: `myset = {item for item in myset if item<tr}`.

Comment: You can replace the list comprehension with a generator expression (i.e., drop the square brackets). `set` doesn't need a list, just an iterable.

Comment: the issue is I have many lines within the `if` block, not just `item<tr`, how to deal with this?

Comment: Edit your question to show what you mean by "many lines within the if block".

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`set.intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection) and [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range):

```
>>> tr = 5
>>> myset = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
>>> myset.intersection(range(tr + 1))
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
>>> myset & set(range(tr + 1))
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
>>>
```

As you can see, everything greater than `tr` is removed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you'll have with this is you can't modify a collection in place while you're iterating over it, so you'll need to filter and reassign to my_set instead. There are a number of ways you can do this.

**Example 1: Comprehension**

```
my_set = {item for item in myset if item < tr }
```

**Example 2: Filter**

```
def my_filter(item):
    item < tr

my_set = filter(my_filter, my_set)
```

**Example 2a: Filter with lambda**

```
my_set = filter(lambda x: x < tr, my_set)
```

**Example 3: For loop**

```
new_set = {}
for item in my_set:
    if item < tr:
        new_set.add(item)
my_set = new_set
```

So if we were to apply 2A to your code, roughly because you're not showing a lot of variable definitions:

```
def calc_len(node):
    #return the length here using your calculation

A_nodes = filter(lambda x: calc_len(x) < th, A_nodes)
```